# WordPress: Styles and other resources not loading

Tags: php, html, wordpress, hosting

I've come across a strange issue, only the home page loads all other resources like images, styles, sub-pages give 404.

If I move the same files to a new server and db everything works well.

url: http://client.vdur.de/client_webpreview/shop/
hosting provider: https://kas.all-inkl.com/

The same site on Godaddy server works fine, something is wrong with this host's server unable to figure out what, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you checked Site URL?

Comment: Yes I did it, it's not the culprit it's the same as the one being used

Comment: Change all url in DB table insert all url like this http://client.vdur.de/client_webpreview/shop/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/1-1-300x300.jpg

Comment: Thanks @Kheteshkumawat I'll try that

Comment: I think somehow your resource path is defined wrong.  Have a thorough look over DB and also the configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed url current domain  all images,css and js file work is fine

Remove this old url

http://transfer.vdur.de/client_webpreview/shop/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/cropped-Screen-Shot-2016-07-14-at-2.20.50-AM.png

New you domain url like this

http://client.vdur.de/client_webpreview/shop/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/cropped-Screen-Shot-2016-07-14-at-2.20.50-AM.png